# Getting Different Size Of Attachment Images

Tags: theme-development, attachments, images, cropping

I'm confused, because there are a lots of functions about attachments . I've tried a lots of functions. I'm setting a *featured image* for my every blog post.

I have to get different sizes of this image. FOr example a need this variations of *featured image*

600px*400px

300px*150px

64px*64px

(Images can be cropped).

I'm adding these new image sizes (in `functions.php`):

```
add_image_size('custombig', 600, 400, TRUE);
add_image_size('customsmall', 300, 152, TRUE);
add_image_size('customimage', 64, 64, TRUE);
```

(in `single.php`)

```
 <?php
        // inside a Loop
        if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ))
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'customsmall' );
    ?>
    <img alt="" src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
```

But it's printing full size of image. Not cropping or resizing it.

Can you teach me getting different sizes of attached images, or suggest me a few articles about this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have defined the featured image for each post with using

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'custombig' ); // or another custom size name ?>
```

should be enough, for info you can read:

http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/11/16/everything-you-need-to-know-about-wordpress-2-9s-post-image-feature

http://markjaquith.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/new-in-wordpress-2-9-post-thumbnail-images/

Or here there is good info too:

[How wordpress handle upload images and how to use them in the code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35074/how-wordpress-handle-upload-images-and-how-to-use-them-in-the-code/35095)

Answer (score 2):

Is it possible that you defined these custom image sizes after the images in question were already uploaded? If so, you'll need to re-generate the thumbnails for these images, since WP doesn't automatically retroactively create new image sizes.

I personally use [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) for this. It's great.

Answer (score 1):

**You should try using it like this:**

```
<?php
    // inside a Loop
    if (has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID ))
        $imageBig = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array(600, 400) );
        $imageMid = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array(300, 152) );
        $imageSmall = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), array(64, 64) );
?>
<img alt="" src="<?php echo $imageBig; ?>" />
<img alt="" src="<?php echo $imageMid; ?>" />
<img alt="" src="<?php echo $imageSmall; ?>" />
```

.
Hope This helps :)
Cheers, Sagive.

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
// code copied from adjacent_image_link() in wp-include/media.php
$attachments = array_values(get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->post_parent, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID') ));
foreach ( $attachments as $k => $attachment )
  if ( $attachment->ID == $post->ID )
    break;

$next_url =  isset($attachments[$k+1]) ? get_permalink($attachments[$k+1]->ID) : get_permalink($attachments[0]->ID);
$prev_url =  isset($attachments[$k-1]) ? get_permalink($attachments[$k-1]->ID) : get_permalink($attachments[0]->ID);
?>
```

sample : [images](http://www.images2015.com/)